# Google Maps info window blink on mouseover listener... how to stop it from blinking?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created a jsfiddle as an example  http://fiddle.jshell.net/WBaXx/

In the result panel you will see google map and text "abcdefghijk" ... I wanted when user mouseover these text let the info windows pop up.

I successfully wrote the script but I am having a small problem is that when user move their mouse from letter "a" to "k" info windows blink.

The problem is because these text are in different html tags but BUT I am listening to mouseover of the parent html which is DIV. So this should not happen isn't it.

Any help ?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the flicker is caused by the "info window" being opened again - even though it is already open.

you can use

`if (!infowindow.getMap())`

to check is the info window is already open

http://fiddle.jshell.net/WBaXx/6/

Comment: nice :) i was about to answer it was related to `generateTriggerCallback()`, since the flicker didnt happen with `$('#testid').on('hover', function() {google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "click")})`

Comment: @Patch: this work great if i have single infowindows on the map.But if i have many then the others info won't pop up. Can you please tweak it  a little more :) or else I might have to go for jquery solution  by RASG

Comment: @RASG your solution also works great EXCEPT when i have many info windows. How I can solve it :S ... and I guess thats why i need that generateTriggerCallback()

Comment: @cjmling: ok. update your fiddle with more than one infowindow and i'll see if i can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery in your page, then you can use mouseenter/mouseleave to control the triggering of your events.

From the api page @ http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

> ... mouseover fires when the pointer moves into the child
>   element as well, while mouseenter fires only when the pointer moves
>   into the bound element.

Your jsfiddle updated below

http://fiddle.jshell.net/WBaXx/26/

Comment: The flicker will happen every time the event is triggered.  In the example I provided that only happens when the div containing the text is entered, not when moving across the elements inside the div, which is the problem that was described.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the answer and for the info for jquery mouseenter/mouseleave and others :)

Comment: OK your solution work great too with single infowindows .. but not with many... how to do that.. plz :)